# Criar nova instancia no MySQL

Tags: mysql

Estou tentando criar uma nova instancia do MySQL em uma máquina que já possui ele instalado. Fiz o processo manual de criar um novo diretório e configurar o arquivo `.ini`, porém no momento de iniciar o serviço é apresentado o seguinte erro:

> O serviço de "NomeDaInstancia" não pode ser iniciado
>
> Para obter mais ajuda, digite NET HELPMSG 3534.

Alguém conhece alguma outra forma de criar uma nova instancia no mysql, com nova senha, nova porta etc?

Eu fiz isso recentemente no Sql Server e é bem simples, basta instalar novamente que é criado uma nova instancia.

Comment: você alterou a porta TCP ?

Comment: Alterei, tentei a 3307 e 3308.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você poderia utilizar o **mysql_multi** para rodar duas instâncias de banco no mesmo servidor. Você deve observar que para se ter uma grande vantagem sobre essa configuração, o ideal é utilizar cada **banco de dados** sobre **discos rígidos** diferentes do servidor. Uma vez que o maior gargalo é geralmente sobre o disco. As configurações se mantém as mesmas originais no my.cnf a diferença é que vai ter que criar dois blocos **server** com as configurações distintas para cada banco.

Existem vários documentações extensas sobe o mysql_multi estou anexando esse **how to**  [mysql](https://dzone.com/articles/mysqldmulti-how-run-multiple) de como se configura mas pode efetuar outras pesquisas.